# Can't add worksheets to an excel file through my R script

Tags: java, r, excel

I'm trying to create a workbook with several spreadsheets where I have to pass three data frames to each sheet. However, I'm having problems creating the sheets, having the following error:

> Error in .jcall(wb, "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet;",
>   "createSheet",  :    method createSheet with signature
>   (D)Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet; not found

I'm using the xlsx package and the relevant code part is the following:

```
wb <- createWorkbook(type="xlsx")
saveWorkbook(wb, 'output.xlsx')

for (i in year)
{
  sheet.1 <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = i)
  data.filter <- realdata[realdata$year_ == i,]
  data.filter <- data.filter[data.filter$month_ >= month[1],]
  data.filter <- data.filter[data.filter$month_ <= month[4],]
  ptable_data_usado <- cast(data.filter, mondat ~ BASE, value = "myidx")
  correl_usado <- cor(ptable_data_usado)
  addDataFrame(correl_usado, sheet = i, startRow = 0, startColumn = 0)
  ptable_data_prx <- cast(data.filter, mondat ~ NearestBaseName, value = "myidx")
  correl_prx <- cor(ptable_data_prx)
  addDataFrame(correl_prx, sheet = i, startRow = 14, startColumn = 0)

}
```

Answer (score 8):

I ran into a similar problem. My solution was to coerce sheet name into a character.

So in your case it might be

```
sheet.1 <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = as.character(i))
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

xlsx package is using rJava to call functions written in JAVA from the APACHE POI project for functionality. 
The function to creat worksheet is declared as:

```
public XSSFSheet createSheet(java.lang.String sheetname)
```

this means that you need to pass a string to the function. Return back to R, the sheet name must be a character vector. @Oleksii-Sh answer is right.

Or you can use:

```
sheet.1 <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = paste0("sheet", i))
```

if you want to name it sheet1, sheet2 ...

Answer (score 0):

Can't be positive without a reproducible example, but it looks like the problem is the two lines where you have `sheet = i`. Instead, it should be `sheet = sheet.1`.

In addition, `startRow` and `startColumn` need to be integers greater than zero, though that would give an out-of-allowable-range error, rather than a not-found error.

Also, `saveWorkbook(wb, 'output.xlsx')` should come after the loop.

Comment: Tried that but I'm still having the same problem. Thought that it could be the fact that I was naming it dynamically with i, but that's not the problem as well

Comment: Still shooting in the dark here, but `startRow=0` and `startColumn=0` should cause errors (they have to be positive integers), though not a "not found" error.

Comment: Tried that as well with no sucess. I think the problem is not on adding data but on creating the sheet. The file is created with sucess, but empty.

Comment: To see where the error is, you should set a value for `year` and run each line of code outside the loop. The file is empty because you saved it before you ran the loop.

Comment: Even out side of the loop I have trouble on that function, so there's where the problem lies